# Use different authorize attributes for controllers to access the same logic from different environments

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, facebook-c#-sdk, authorize-attribute

I have an ASP.NET MVC website, where most of my controllers are decorated with Authorize attributes, to enforce forms authentication.

I'm about to make this website available on Facebook via a Facebook app, but for my FB users I want to use a different authentication/authorization, I want to use CanvasAuthorize attribute on my controllers.

The problem is that I can't use both on my controllers/actions, because then both of them would be enforced to access the relevant action, but I want only Authorize for the normal website and I want only the CanvasAuthorize when the website is accessed from FB (via FB app).

I started to

1. refactor hugely my existing controllers to 'controllerhelpers'
2. make existing controllers (with authorize attribute) use the controllerhelpers relevant method
3. create new controllers (decorated with CanvasAuthorize) for the FB-app, which use the relevant controllerhelper methods also

But this is huge work, and I'm not sure whether this is the way to go, or there is a much easier an elegant way to work.

Of course I want to use the same views, and in my cshtmls I'm using specific controllers's Url.Action methods, so with my current approach when I'm inserting action-paths in my cshtmls (for eg. jQuery ajax Url properties) I have to make an if-statement to use for example the 'PersonalController' when the normal website is used and use the 'FBPersonalController' when the website is used as a FB app.

In this case PersonalController is decorated with [Authorize] and FBPersonalController is decorated with [CanvasAuthorize].

So, any feedback is appreciated ;)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you use [Conditional Filter](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/25/conditional-filters.aspx/) to support both [Authorize] and [CanvasAuthorize]? As I tested in a simple ASP.NET MVC3 application, it works. Do you think it helps?

On the other hand, a nice solution would be, if you could change your design, put the authentication stuff in one place, that is, FormsAuthenticationService, FacebookAuthenciationService, and OpenIDAuthencitationService implement an interface called "IAuthenticationService". Call the standard FomsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie method upon completing the Facebook OAuth flow. The Authorize attribute should then work properly. Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139792/how-to-use-authorize-and-facebookauthorize-in-mvc3-web-app-using-mixed-membe) and check code snippets from [here](http://mvcstarter.codeplex.com/) (Create.aspx and SessionController.cs). Please evaluate.

Comment: Dear xoyoja, thank's for the reply, I'm gonna check it, but the website is unavailable for me at this moment :(

Comment: @Csabi, OK. Another question is, is it required to make each controller action method decorated with CanvasAuthorize? Does this work: var auth = new CanvasAuthorizer(); if (auth.Authorize()) { /*... */}?

Comment: No, some of my actions has to remain undecorated (example login and register actions of the AccountController, so users of the 'normal' website (so those which do not access the website via a FB app) can log in and register, but I post my current state in an answer based on your advice.

Comment: @Csabi, thank you, see my updated answer to get something new.

Answer (score 0):

Xoyoja's answer lead me to this solution. I don't mark it as 'accepted answer' because I'm evaluating it, but maybe it is worth discussing:

No, not all of them should be decorated. But with your proposal, I came to the following:

```
IEnumerable<Func<ControllerContext, ActionDescriptor, object>> conditions =
                new Func<ControllerContext, ActionDescriptor, object>[] { 

                    (ctrlCtx, actDesc) =>
                        {
                            if(FacebookWebContext.Current.SignedRequest != null)
                            {
                                return new CanvasAuthorize();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if(ctrlCtx.Controller.GetType() == typeof(AccountController)
                                    && actDesc.ActionName == "LogOn")
                                {
                                    return null;
                                }
                                return new AuthorizeAttribute();
                            }
                        },
            };
```

When my website is accessed from FB, it seems that the SignedRequest is not null, so the CanvasAuthorize can be used.

If my website is accessed from it's normal published url, then I use the AuthorizeAttribute.

The AccountController and "LogOn" action-specific logic is required to allow logging in to the website from the public url. From Facebook the Context contains the Facebook UserID which would implicitely do the authentication.

I'm still thinking about implications, worst-case-scenarios, backdoors whether this could harm me or not.